# React routing problema con babel en navbar

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, webpack, navbar, babeljs

Estoy aprendiendo el uso del routing siguiendo el siguiente [tutorial](https://medium.com/@leonardellifernando/reactjs-navbar-con-bootstrap-y-react-router-85f8ba82edc1). Donde se importa bootstrap  y se usa un navbar para navegar entre paginas. 
Se declaro el componente y la siguiente funcion:

```
getNavLinkClass = (path) => {
    return this.props.location.pathname === path ? 'active' : '';
}
```

Pero al transpilar me genera el siguiente error:

```
getNavLinkClass = (path) => {
|                     ^
|         return this.props.location.pathname === path 
              ?  'active' : '';
|     }
|     render() {

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL)
to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
at parser.next (<anonymous>)
at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
         at run.next (<anonymous>)
      at transform.next (<anonymous>)


 @ ./assets/js/app.js 25:0-56
```

En mi package.json tengo configurado lo siguiente:

```
{
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
"@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.29.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"webpack-notifier": "^1.8.0"
 },
"dependencies": {
"node-sass": "^4.14.0"
}
}
```

**Edit**
Agregue el siguiente archivo .babel

```
{
 "plugins": [
   ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
 ]
}
```

Porque no estaba incorporado. No muestra el primer error pero ahora me genera lo siguiente:

```
Syntax Error: C:\xampp\htdocs\web_cotizacion_repuestos\assets\js\app.js:
  Unexpected token (17:8)

  15 |        render() {
  16 |         return (
> 17 |           <div>
     |             ^
```

Si me pueden orientar como solucionarlo, o tirarme una linea. En mi proyecto no tengo un archivo especifico de babel config, puede ser eso???

Comment: Puedes agregar tu babelrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instala el plugin en dev en el archivo package.json

```
 * npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --save-dev
```

y edita tu archivo .babelrc o créalo en la raíz junto con tu package.json, copia y pega esto

```
{
  "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
      ]
  ]
}
```

Tambien no se te olvide editar tu archivo webpack.config.js agregando esto

```
'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']}]
```

Puedes ver mas detalles sobre la solución en este link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237855/support-for-the-experimental-syntax-classproperties-isnt-currently-enabled/52504340#52504340